# MongoDB: how do you perform this update query

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in my collection that have a top level field called 'foo' which is an array of hashes. I need to be able to go through all my documents and find where db.mycollection.foo contains a hash with the sub property 'name' equal to 'bar'. When that match is done, I need to update a top level field called 'hit' to the value 1.

So just to reiterate the collection is called mycollection. foo is a field that is of type array and contains hashes where each hash has a field called name. If any of the hashes contain name == 'bar', I need to perform the update.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the mondobd documentation for update statements : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
db.mycollection.update({"foo.name": "bar"}, {$set: {"hit": 1}}, false, true);
```

Comment: Just for clarity, the "false" and "true" after the update statement refer to whether a record should be upserted and whether multiple records should be updated as well.  See more info at the mongoDB link provided above by marco-fiset.  Currently if not set to true, mongo will only update one document that matches the query